# Forwarding a blog entry to Facebook using Orchard CMS

Tags: facebook, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm putting together a site using Orchard CMS and I'm trying to find a way to forward blog entries to Facebook when they are published.  I've followed through the tutorial on creating modules and I'm still at an absolute loss as to how to achieve this.  Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why the minus with no answer or explanation?

Comment: So I have abandoned trying to create something on my own and have started using Workflows to do what I want.  One workflow that submits to multiple sites using supplied API's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is workflows.  Just use Workflows built into Orchard and reference the external API's (like Facebook) to get your data posted.  Was way easier than I thought.